# How to solve this functional equation: $2f(x) = f(x-1)+f(x+1)$?

Tags: functional-equations

After some calculations, I came up with this functional equation: $f(x-1)+f(x+1)=2f(x)$. I found linear function is one possible answer, but don't know how to derive it.

I don't know much about the techniques to solve this kind of equation. Can anyone help?

Edited: $f$ is a probability function, that is $0 \leq f \leq 1$, and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Could you give the context of this question? Is anything known about the function $f$?

Comment: $\sin(2n\pi x)$ is also a solution for any $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @MrTopology: I added the context.

Comment: With all these constraints, the only solution is a constant.

Comment: Bounded continuous solutions are not necessarily constant.  $f(x)=\cos^2(k \pi x)$ is a solution for every integer $k$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is not clear what a "probability function" means.  The OP did not specify this.  And a constant function is not a CDF.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I don't know.  It's still not clear hat a "probability function" means.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I'm not going to play this stupid game of guessing.  If you like to do it, then so be it.

Comment: It cannot be not a probability function (cumulative, or density, or mass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $f(x+1)-f(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$ and so $f(x+2)-f(x+1)$ is equal to the same value, and similarly $$f(x+n) - f(x+n-1)=f(x)-f(x-1)$$ for all integer $n$.  This gives $$f(x+n) = (n+1)f(x)-nf(x-1)=n(f(x)-f(x-1)) + f(x)$$ which is linear in integer $n$, though not necessarily linear in real $x$.

If you fix the values of $f(y)$ on $[-1,1)$ then you can give a general solution using rounding and $$f(y) = \lfloor y \rfloor\left(f(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)- f(y-\lfloor y \rfloor-1)\right) + f(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)$$

Comment: This isn't bounded, is it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It can be bounded, in which case it will be periodic

Comment: If $f(x)$ is continuous then $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is constant for all $x$

Comment: Your expression is too general, it allows unbounded solutions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: it was not bounded or continuous when I answered the question.  It cannot be a "probability function" over the real line

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f$ is completely determined by its values on $[0,2)$.  Use recursion to solve for $f$ given its values on $[0,2)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really get your hint. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: With the given constraints, $f$ must be identical on $[0,1)$ and $[1,2)$.

Comment: That is an obvious conclusion from the extra conditions the OP has included.  My answer is a hint, not a solution. The OP should take his own time to arrive at this result on his own.